# Ideal way to brace a gable end wall for sill replacement

Tags: structural, sill-plate

I may have to replace a rotted sill plate in a small single-story + basement house. The house has a gable roof with rafters. The rotted sill is under the front gable wall, and rests on a concrete foundation. The floor joists of the main floor run parallel to the gable wall and the ceiling joists under the attic also run parallel to the wall. The house is old enough that it doesn't really have modern ceiling joists though, and it has full-size 2x4 lumber studs.

I haven't yet determined the level of rot but I suspect it is quite significant so I'm preparing to replace the entire sill later on this summer. I've been doing some research on best ways to correctly support the gable wall for this, and one of the possibilities is attaching studs to the top plate at an angle and then attaching these new studs to a brace on the floor that runs parallel to the wall. Will this work?

Is there anything about the angled stud wall that I need to know or be concerned with? I am going to run this by a structural engineer acquaintance of mine, but wanted to know if there's some glaring concern that I should know about...

Comment: You know the drill: Pics or it didn't happen. Erm.. Pics or we won't be able to help very well. Which way do floor joists run? What do the ceiling joists look like? Etc.

Comment: @FreeMan I understand. But it’s too early for pics. I haven’t exposed the framing yet.

Comment: Nothing at an angle build a temporary wall inside the existing pressure fit will be fine a single plate top and bottom. I have done this many times with a tight pressure fit on the drywall, stucco or plaster, plaster tended to crack the worst and drywall survived the best.